# Date conversion in .net

Tags: asp.net, datetime, datepicker

i have a jquery in my web form which returns the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. how can i convert this to the system datetime format, or is it possible make changes in jquery to return the date in system datetime format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(jquery_date_string, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Or, perhaps, `TryParseExact`

Comment: @JimMischel.. this will return the date in mm/dd/yyyy format?.. but i want it to return the jquery date in system datetime format, which can be anything like dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd or anything else.

Comment: @thejus_r: This gives you a `DateTime` structure, which you can then output in whatever format you like. See DateTime.ToString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx